# php form takes a long time to receive

Tags: php, forms, time

This is a form that gets sent to an email address. It takes unusually long to receive, anywhere from 20 minutes to 4 hours. Can anyone spot anything with my code that might be causing it to take so long? Possibly something with the headers or donot reply?

*additional info:*

- This website is protected behind an htaccess password restriction for now. Removing htaccess password seems to make no difference on sending time.
- On this website there are 2 other php forms sent via `mail` function, and the time to receive the email for these normal, about 2-5 minutes. So I think I can rule out host or ISP.
- My best guess at why it's taking so long is perhaps something is causing it activate a spam filter...maybe having it set up for multiple recipients, or the way I have my headers configured, or the `-f donotreply....` line.

Can anyone recognize **anything** in this code that might be causing it take so long to receive?

```
<?php
$email = str_replace("href=\"",'',$_POST['element_5_list']);
$email2 = str_replace('\"','',$email);
$email3 =str_replace("\\",'',$email2);
$name = $_POST['element_0_name'];
$email = str_replace(' ','',$_POST['element_1_email']);
$company = $_POST['element_2_company'];
$date = $_POST['element_3_date'];
$comment = $_POST['element_4_comment'];
$list = $_POST['element_5_list'];
$mails = array();
foreach($_POST['rep'] as $rep_num) {
    if($rep_num == 02) {$rep_num = 'a@website.com';}        
    if($rep_num == 03) {$rep_num = 'b@website.com';}        
    if($rep_num == 04) {$rep_num = 'c@website.com';}
    $mails[] = $rep_num;
}
$email_to = implode(',', $mails);
$email_subject = "Website Wishlist Form";
$email_message = "\n\n";
function clean_string($string) {
    $bad = array ("content-type", "bcc:", "to:", "cc:", "href");
    return str_replace($bad, "",$string);
}
$email_message .= '<div style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;padding-left: 90px;font-weight: 100;font-size: 14px;color: #2a2a2a;"><table width="800px" height="730px;"border="0" cellspacing="10" background="http://www.website.com//email_bg2.jpg">
                <tr>
                <td style="vertical-align:top;padding-left:88px;">
                <h2 style="padding-top:30px;padding-left:90px;"> Wishlist Order</h2><p>Someone will respond to you shortly.</p><br>';
$email_message .= '<p style="max-width:750px;">Name: '. $name .'<br /></p>';
$email_message .= "<p style=\"max-width:750px;\">Email: " .clean_string($email) . "<br></p>";
$email_message .= "<p style=\"max-width:750px;\">Company: " .$company. "<br></p>";
$email_message .= "<p style=\"max-width:750px;\">Date Required: " .$date. "<br></p>";
$email_message .= "<p style=\"max-width:750px;\">Comment: " .$comment. "</span><br><br></p>";
$email_message .= '<u>Items on Wishlist:</u><style>tr:nth-child(2n) </style> </u><br>'.$email3. '</table>';
$email_message .= "</div>";
$headers = 'From:&nbsp;'. $name. " \r\n".$headers .= "MIME-Version:1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8; \r\n";
$add = "-f donotreply@website.com";
'X-Mailer: PHP/' .phpversion();
mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers, $add);
?>
```

Comment: I have tried to send an e-mail with your headers and stuff - it works fine for me. Maybe your E-Mail provider has some trouble at the moment? Try it with a different email address.

Comment: wow that is taking a long time. Firstly hardcode the `to` address so it only gets sent to your email address. If you don't receive the email it could be a problem with the PHP mail function not being setup correctly. If this is the case you either need to fix the problem int he PHP.ini file or you could try use something like PHPmailer (http://phpmailer.worxware.com/) and set this up to use SMTP settings.

Answer (score 0):

sending one email to multiple recipints is not a good practice... there could be several reasonons for this failure
 - your host provider has limit of sent emails
 - a bunch of emaill recipients are maybe on the same provider, and they also could have limit of max received emails at the same time

from my point of view, the best practice is to create single email ( store it in a variable ), and then loop through all recipients, and send seperate email for every recipient.. so instead of sending one email to X recipients, send one email to one recipient